# git push требует название репозитория и ветки

Tags: git

Помогите разобраться, как упростить себе процесс git push.

Я создавал локальный репозиторий в существующей директории проекта, и потом заливал на гитхаб. При этом возникали проблемы, которые я решил ключом -f. Сейчас для того, чтобы запушить изменения, требуется явно указать название репозитория и ветку, то есть вместо `git push` мне приходится набирать `git push my_todo_list master`. Как вернуть удобную возможность пушить изменения без указания названия и ветки?

Answer (score 3):

#### Посмотрите в [документации к git-config](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config):

> `push.default`
>   Defines the action git push should take if no refspec is explicitly given. Different values are well-suited for specific workflows; for instance, in a purely central workflow (i.e. the fetch source is equal to the push destination), upstream is probably what you want.

Краткий перевод:

> `push.default` позволяет определить действие по умолчанию при использовании команды `git.push` без использования специальных параметров.

---

#### Примеры использования:

Посмотреть текущую конфигурацию:

```
git config --global push.default
```

Установить новую конфигурацию:

```
git config --global push.default current
```

Здесь

> `current` – push the current branch to a branch of the same name

Перевод:

> `current` – делать `push` текущей ветки в ветку с таким же именем

Остальные возможные варианты можете увидеть в документации, ссылку я привёл выше.

Используя этот вариант, далее вы сможете использовать просто `git push`.

---

[<sub>Оригинальный ответ на enSO</sub>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/948397/7519767)